# Does user still have access to firestore after their token id has expired

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

It says here [Firebase Auth Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) that **Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour**. Does that mean if a user `signInAnonymously` and a hour later the user id token expires and the user didn't re Sign-In. Will that user still have access to Cloud-Firestore with rules that only `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication SDKs automatically renew ID tokens behind the scenes, typically about 5 minutes before the current ID token expires.

So: yes, if the ID token expires, the user won't have access to Firestore data anymore that requires authentication, but this usually doesn't happen because the SDK automatically renews the ID token.

Comment: "but this usually doesn't happen because the SDK automatically renews the ID token." Is this only if `getIdToken(forceRefresh)` is called?

Comment: No, the token refresh happens automatically - the SDK takes care of it behind the scenes. You should only call `getIdToken(true)` if you want to force an earlier refresh, which is a rare occurrence.